# Running Jar file with embedded JRE using batch script . 

Tags: java

If i want to embed JRE with my application, i have this directory structure.

```
+---jre
|   +---bin
RunMyApp.bat
myApp.jar
```

i have added this statement in RunMyApp.bat to access the java.exe

```
jre\bin\java.exe -help
```

Then how to run the myApp.jar, using RunMyApp.bat script?

i have tried this one, but not succeed

```
jre\bin\java.exe  -jar "%cd%\..\..\myApp.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry to your MANIFEST.MF (under META-INF directory) for the `Main-Class` attribute and say `jre\bin\java.exe -jar <your-jar-filename>`